# Google maps cluster not show all markers

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gmaps4rails

I have many markers in clusters, one of them with 3 markers in it. 
[image]

But when I open it, I see only one marker.
[image]

If I open developer console in browser or change zoom I see all of them.

[image]

What I need to do to prevent it

P.S: I catch this error only in Safari. In Firefox and Chrome everything work fine

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be a CSS problem. No JavaScript code path differences are apparent between Firefox (which works) and Safari (which does not).

In the Cluster.prototype.addMarker() function, removing the "this.markers_[i].setMap(null);" lines, which caused the clusters to remain on the map, though they are cut off as though by a bounding box (see attached screenshot; note that both clusters are cut off at the bottom, at different positions). This leads to believe that the action of hiding the existing markers when creating the cluster icon is causing the cluster itself to be hidden by a misplaced bounding box. This might be the reason for your markers being not displayed at a certain zoom level or zoom action.

This is a problem(bug) with Safari 5.1, you can try with an older version 5.0.5 or the newer version 5.1.1, it should work as expected.